# Outlook Email created in VBA using a template converts to plain text when saved

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Below is the code that I am running in ThisOutlookSession. The code is meant to check all incoming emails and if the email is from a certain email address and contains a specific string in the subject then a new email is created from a template and the triggering email is attached and the email is then sent out to a different email address. This portion all works fine.

Also to note I am using windows 10 and office 2016.

The problem that I am having is the email is converted to plain text unless it is displayed first. The template that I have created is saved as a HTML formatted message. I have tried adding lines such as

```
NewMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
NewMsg.save
```

But this doesn't seem to work as the email that is sent was still in the plain text format. If I add the following to that the message it basically works.

```
NewMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
NewMsg.save
NewMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
NewMsg.save
```

However the above block of code removes a lot of the formatting that was saved in my template such as different fonts/ font sizes.

Am I missing something about working with templates in VBA?

Also The problem that I am having with displaying the message first is two things. The obvious one is the flash that this causes because the message is briefly displayed. The second is my default signature is also added to the displayed message but I wanted to use a custom signature that I built into my template.

Here is my full code with sensitive information removed.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' default local Inbox
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim NewMsg As Outlook.MailItem

    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then

        Set Msg = item

        If Msg.SenderEmailAddress <> "example@example.com" Then GoTo Skip

        If InStr(1, Msg.Subject, "Specific String") > 0 Then 'checks if subject contains the proper string

        Set NewMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("Template Path")

        Msg.Subject = Replace(Msg.Subject, "Old Subject", "New subject")
        Msg.Save

        NewMsg.HTMLBody = NewMsg.HTMLBody
        NewMsg.Attachments.Add Msg

        NewMsg.Recipients.Add("Example@Example.com")
        NewMsg.Subject = Msg.Subject

        NewMsg.Save
        NewMsg.Send

    End If

  End If

Skip:
ProgramExit:

  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to reset the HTMLBody property (Msg.HTMLBody = Msg.HTMLBody) immediately after creating the message?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko That worked perfect. If you write it as a solution I will mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: All done. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset the `HTMLBody` property - that will force HTML format:

```
Msg.HTMLBody = Msg.HTMLBody
```

Comment: Why is this helpful? I do not understand this magic. This single, seemingly useless, line fixed everything

Comment: I experienced a similar issue at a coworker's computer, even though the same macro worked fine on  mine. Seems that there is a bug that will create a message but lose all formatting. Unless you set the body value again. I do not understand the actual root cause, but I can confirm that this fixed the problem.