# Email created in VB.Net using Outlook HTML template (*.oft) converted in plain text when sent

Tags: html, vb.net, email, outlook

I am having an issue with my implementation, below. The script does a loop on all messages in a previously selected folder (oFolder) and, until there is no more messages (MailItem) in that folder, it does the loop and send a reply. But the message created from a template (*.oft - Outlook Model) is converted to plain text after send, except if is to a internal email address, in the same domain as the sender, then the formatting is kept intact.

I have tried some solutions, like resetting the .HTMLBody after creating the message, but to no avail. Maybe I am putting the solution in the wrong place, don't know for sure. But here's what I have as a code:

```
Dim originalMail, loopControl, newMail, headerMail, footerMail As MailItem
Dim snd2Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim myRecipient As Recipients
Dim thisRecipient As Recipient
Dim oSubject, oMessage, oMessageNew, oRecipient, oMailDate, oMailTo, thisSenderAddr, tempTemplate As String
Dim objPropNewName, objPropNewDateTime As UserProperty
Dim thisClassName As Type


While oFolder.Items.Count > 0
    loopControl = oFolder.Items.GetFirst
    If TypeName(loopControl) = "MailItem" Then 
        originalMail = loopControl 

        originalMail.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML 'here tried implementing the post solution, not working
        originalMail.HTMLBody = originalMail.HTMLBody
        originalMail.Save()

        myRecipient = originalMail.ReplyRecipients 'the original message comes from a form in a web page, that contains the persons email set in the Reply-To field

        newMail = OutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(tempTemplate) 'creates a new message from a template in the tempTemplate location, a local folder with *.oft files selected by the user

        objPropNewName = newMail.UserProperties.Add("Custom Property", OlUserPropertyType.olText, True) 'sensitive custom property set by the organisation for control purposes
        objPropNewName.Value = tmpUserName 'value to be stored in the property
        objPropNewDateTime = newMail.UserProperties.Add("Another Custom Property", OlUserPropertyType.olDateTime, True)
        objPropNewDateTime.Value = tmpDateTime

        If originalMail.ReplyRecipients.Count > 0 Then 'since the message may come from a web form or directly via Replay, it is important to get the SMTP email address in the .To field. This block makes sure the .To field will get a valid SMTP address
            Try
                thisRecipient = myRecipient.Item(1)
                thisRecipient.Resolve()
                If thisRecipient.Resolved() Then
                    thisUser = thisRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
                    If thisUser Is Nothing Then
                        oRecipient = myRecipient.Item(1).Address.ToString()
                    Else
                        oRecipient = thisRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString()
                    End If
                Else
                    oRecipient = myRecipient.Item(1).Address.ToString()
                End If
                'oRecipientMail = myRecipient.Item(1).AddressEntry.Address.ToString() 
            Catch ex As System.Exception
                PrintCurrentLineException(ex, thisClassName.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)
                oRecipient = myRecipient.Item(1).Address.ToString() 'if there is an error because the sender is not a Exchange user, it will be a SMTP address, so get that value instead
            End Try
        Else
            If originalMail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
                oRecipient = originalMail.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString()
            Else
                oRecipient = originalMail.SenderEmailAddress 
            End If
        End If

        With originalMail 
            oSubject = .Subject 
            oMessage = .HTMLBody 
            oMailTo = .To
            oMailDate = Format(.SentOn, "dddd, dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm")
        End With

        If originalMail.ReadReceiptRequested = True Or originalMail.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True Then
            Dim thisEntry, thisSubject, thisDate As String
            Dim thisAccessor As PropertyAccessor
            thisAccessor = originalMail.PropertyAccessor
            thisEntry = thisAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E").ToString()
            thisSubject = originalMail.Subject
            thisDate = Format(originalMail.SentOn, "ddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
            OBGWorkerModulo1.CancelAsync()
            Thread.Sleep(300)
            MsgBox("One of the messages in this lot of " & i1 & " messages have a delivery or a read recipe active." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The application cannot work correctly. Please mark the message as read or reply to it manually." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Sender: " & oRecipient & vbNewLine & "Subject: " & thisSubject & vbNewLine & "Received in: " & thisDate & vbNewLine & "Message EntryID: " & thisEntry, vbDefaultButton1 + vbExclamation + vbOKOnly + vbApplicationModal + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Read/Delivery Recipe")
            errorLocal = True 'variable to point an internal error
            Exit Try
        End If

        With newMail 
            .To = oRecipient 
            .Subject = oSubject 
            thisSenderAddr = LCase(outServer) '
            Try
                If tmpChkHeader = True And tmpChkFooter = False Then 'an internal option to set header or/and footer as a template to be applied to the reply message
                    oMessageNew = "<html><style>body {font-family: calibri; font-size: 11.25pt;}</style>" & headerMail.HTMLBody & newMail.HTMLBody & "<body><br><hr>" & "---- Your message ----<br><b>From:</b><a href="" mailto:" & oRecipient & """>" & oRecipient & "</a><br><b>Sent on:</b> " & oMailDate & "<br><b>To:</b> " & oMailTo & " (<a href=""mailto:" & thisSenderAddr & """>" & thisSenderAddr & "</a>)<br><b>Subject:</b> " & oSubject & "<br><br><blockquote>" & oMessage & "</blockquote></body></html>" 
                ElseIf tmpChkHeader = False And tmpChkFooter = True Then
                    oMessageNew = "<html><style>body {font-family: calibri; font-size: 11.25pt;}</style>" & newMail.HTMLBody & footerMail.HTMLBody & "<body><br><hr>" & "---- Your message ----<br><b>From:</b><a href="" mailto:" & oRecipient & """>" & oRecipient & "</a><br><b>Sent on:</b> " & oMailDate & "<br><b>To:</b> " & oMailTo & " (<a href=""mailto:" & thisSenderAddr & """>" & thisSenderAddr & "</a>)<br><b>Subject:</b> " & oSubject & "<br><br><blockquote>" & oMessage & "</blockquote></body></html>" 
                ElseIf tmpChkHeader = True And tmpChkFooter = True Then
                    oMessageNew = "<html><style>body {font-family: calibri; font-size: 11.25pt;}</style>" & headerMail.HTMLBody & newMail.HTMLBody & footerMail.HTMLBody & "<body><br><hr>" & "---- Your message ----<br><b>From:</b><a href="" mailto:" & oRecipient & """>" & oRecipient & "</a><br><b>Sent on:</b> " & oMailDate & "<br><b>To:</b> " & oMailTo & " (<a href=""mailto:" & thisSenderAddr & """>" & thisSenderAddr & "</a>)<br><b>Subject:</b> " & oSubject & "<br><br><blockquote>" & oMessage & "</blockquote></body></html>" 
                Else
                    oMessageNew = "<html><style>body {font-family: calibri; font-size: 11.25pt;}</style>" & newMail.HTMLBody & "<body><br><hr>" & "---- Your message ----<br><b>From:</b><a href="" mailto:" & oRecipient & """>" & oRecipient & "</a><br><b>Sent on:</b> " & oMailDate & "<br><b>To:</b> " & oMailTo & " (<a href=""mailto:" & thisSenderAddr & """>" & thisSenderAddr & "</a>)<br><b>Subject:</b> " & oSubject & "<br><br><blockquote>" & oMessage & "</blockquote></body></html>" 
                End If
            Catch ex As System.Exception
                PrintCurrentLineException(ex, thisClassName.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)
                oMessageNew = "<html><style>body {font-family: calibri; font-size: 11.25pt;}</style>" & newMail.HTMLBody & "<body><br><hr>" & "---- Your message ----<br><b>From:</b><a href="" mailto:" & oRecipient & """>" & oRecipient & "</a><br><b>Sent on:</b> " & oMailDate & "<br><b>To:</b> " & oMailTo & " (<a href=""mailto:" & thisSenderAddr & """>" & thisSenderAddr & "</a>)<br><b>Subject:</b> " & oSubject & "<br><br><blockquote>" & oMessage & "</blockquote></body></html>" 
            End Try
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = outServer 'server mail set on a config file
            .HTMLBody = oMessageNew
            .Send() 
        End With
        
        If sndReply = True Then 'if the sent event is all right, this variable is set to true       
            originalMail.Unread = False 
            originalMail.Move(snd2Folder) 'a outlook folder to where the original messages are moved after replied to
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(originalMail)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newMail)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objPropNewName)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objPropNewDateTime)
        End If

        intCnt += 1
            i2 += 1
    Else
        Dim controlTypeName As String = Information.TypeName(loopControl)
        MsgBox("One item in the selected folder is not a valid email message. Remove the item to another folder or select another folder before running this lot again." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Control Type: " & controlTypeName & vbNewLine & $"Selected folder: {oFolder.Name}", vbDefaultButton1 + vbExclamation + vbOKOnly + vbApplicationModal + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Wrong control type")
        errorLocal = True
        Exit Try
    End If
End While
```

I have tried the solution in this post, but no luck so far:

[Outlook Email created in VBA using a template converts to plain text when saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346555/outlook-email-created-in-vba-using-a-template-converts-to-plain-text-when-saved)

I have a very similar code without the loop that keeps the formatting after sending.

The main difference is that this code above does not display the message before sending, because it would slow down the process (having to display each and every message before sending).

Is there a way to display without displaying, of sorts, like commanding the message to be formatted the way it is in the template before sending?

Comment: This the VBA forum.  Please move your post to the correct forum.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I don't see how to move this somewhere else. I didn't even knew there was other forums. I just clicked the button Ask a Question and here I am. How can I do that moving thing?

Comment: I believe freeflow misspoke. You cannot move the post, only not use inappropriate tags. This **Q & A site** expects you to not cast a broad net as you might in a (social media) forum. VBA watchers do not want to see a non-VBA question pop up to them.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I meant no harm. I will remove the VBA tag so this can be settled. Thanks.